# Are strictly concave functions robust to "small changes"?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose that there exists an $a_0\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f\left(x,a_0\right)$ is strictly concave in $x$. Is it true that there exists a ball $A$ around $a_0$ such that $f\left(x,a\right)$ is concave in $x$ for $a\in A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This not true; essentially all we need to do is set
$$f(x,a)=-x^2+ag(x)$$
and pick $g(x)$ to be any function whose second derivative is not bounded above. Then $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}f(x,a)=-2+ag''(x).$$
Since $g''(x)$ is not bounded above, there is some $x$ for which this is positive for any $a>0$.

An explicit example of this would be
$$f(x,a)=-x^2+a\sin(x^2).$$

You can even do a little worse - consider a function like $f(x,a)=-x^2+a|x|$. This gives a counterexample even you wanted $f$ to be a function $f:[-1,1]\times \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks! Any additional assumptions I could make on $f$ to make the statement true? Would assuming that $f$ is continuously differentiable work?

Comment: The first example of an $f$ I give is continuously differentiable (in fact, it's an analytic function - way better than just continuously differentiable). I can't think of any reasonable conditions that aren't trivial. Really, the answer is that concavity is a sensitive condition.

Comment: What if the domain of $f$ is a compact set instead, and that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable? Its seems that we can prevent $g''$ from exploding in that case.

Comment: @user_lambda Unfortunately, you can't stop $f_{xx}(x,a_0)$ from vanishing somewhere - and what matters if the ratio $g''/f_{xx}$. For instance, consider the function $f:[-1,1]\times \mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ given by $f(x,a)=-x^4+ax^2$.

Comment: Hum, I thought that *strict* concavity would prevent $f_{xx}$ from going to 0 but that does not seem to be true, TIL. Thanks!